# Are there settings in Crystal Reports that modify sort order of data sources?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, sorting, crystal-reports, subreport

I'm working with Crystal Reports in VB.NET in Visual Studio 2005.

I have a List(Of Stuff) that I've sorted according to one of the object's members.

I've verified in the debugger that the list is sorted correctly.

When I define my list as the data source, as in

```
rptDetails.Subreports.Item("rptSubReport").SetDataSource(theListOfStuff)
```

and view the report, the list is reversed.

So, looking for a workaround, I said, "OK, I'll sort the list backwards before binding it."

The list still appeared backwards in the report.

So something's happening, and I think it's within the report definition, because I don't know where else the sort order could be changed.  Any suggestions?

(Oh, forgot to mention that I used the report design facilities within VS to lay out the report.)

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link might help: [MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/800f383f-0577-4189-9630-bef997e1d9a0)

This is what I suspected:
CR does not retain any previous sorting for a dataset. Its default sort is based on the first column in ascending order. You have to reapply your sorting criteria to CR.

You could just try:
Dim subRpt as ReportDocument
subRpt = rptDetails.Subreports.Item("rptSubReport")
subRpt.DataDefinition.SortFields(0).SortDirection = CrystalDecisions.Shared.SortDirection.DescendingOrder